# Need to get a lookup from a table field which is having duplicate values.(I need only distinct values in lookup)

Tags: axapta, lookup, microsoft-dynamics, ax

Hi I have a form where i need to get a lookup from a table field which is having duplicate values. I need to get only the distinct values in the loookup. How can i acheive it?

Example.

```
RmTable
field1 field2 field3
t1      jyo     abc
t2      jyo     cdd
t3      jyo     ccc
t4      Kim     dd
t5      pete    ss
t6      kim     sssw
```

I have a form which is having a field. I need to get lookup of distinct values from field2.
Can you please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of the [select statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa656402.aspx) in Dynamics AX X++ code has no `distinct` keyword like it exists in SQL. There are workarounds, however:

- Create a new table or enum that contains the possible values of the lookup field and do the lookup on that table or enum (that is the workaround I would recommend)
- Create at runtime of the lookup a `List` of all the possible lookup values and then use the `SysLookup::lookupList` function

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply. I used groupby in the query inside lookup method and it worked.

Comment: @Raas: That works, too. You might want to put that down as an answer and accept it. It is ok to answer your own questions.

Answer (score 0):

public void lookup()

{

```
Query                   query = new Query();
QueryBuildDataSource    queryBuildDataSource;

SysTableLookup  sysTableLookup = sysTableLookup::newParameters(tableNum(APDicQuotationsControl), this);
;

sysTableLookup.addLookupfield(fieldNum(APDicQuotationsControl, Version));
queryBuildDataSource = query.addDataSource(tableNum(APDicQuotationsControl));

queryBuildDataSource.addSortField(fieldnum(APDicQuotationsControl, Version));
queryBuildDataSource.addOrderByField(fieldnum(APDicQuotationsControl, Version));
queryBuildDataSource.orderMode(OrderMode::GroupBy);

sysTableLookup.parmQuery(query);
sysTableLookup.performFormLookup();
```

}